# How to force component to route without item id in url?

Tags: joomla-3.x

What I am trying to do is get the router for the component (iCagenda) to work with a url of this form:

mysite.com/index.php/events/register?eid=1111, where I can map eid to the item id

The deafult is mysite.com/index.php/events/id-alias/register

In the component's router, there is a function iCagendaBuildRoute( &$query )

This function returns $segments (for the url string I guess), and I have it working so that the $segments array is the same whether the url form is default or as I have above. I thought that was good sign.

But then in the function iCagendaParseRoute( $segments )

The $segments variable is not the same as returned in iCagendaBuildRoute.

I think it has something to do with the local versus global variables. Joomla must be doing some additional checking which is resulting in the passed version of $segments to be different...

I can't figure this out...

Comment: Can you check function calling of `iCagendaParseRoute($segments)`? Before function call they might have changed in data.

Comment: Is mysite.com/index.php/events/register a menu item on the site or is it the result of JRoute::_(index.php?option=your_component&so_on..') ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but I just got it to work fine by making sure that the component router created the $var array as if the url was like the default url.

Answer (score 1):

If you are passing value such as `?eid=111`. You can retrieve that with Joomla Input method.

Try this

```
$id = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('eid', 0);
```

First argument of get is key name of URL query string, where second argument is default value in case there is no value detected for `eid`.

Comment: I restated my question. Hopefully it is more clear now.